# Nginx Download Server

Tags: nginx, server, proxy, download

I have set up an Nginx download server with three nodes running on three M1 Mac Minis with 1 gigabit connections. However, I'm experiencing a bottleneck where having 5 or 6 concurrent downloads can slow my download speeds down to 1 Mb or less of download speeds. I was under the impression that with three separate servers, I wouldn't be so limited. the servers have a read and write speed of 3000 megabytes and I would think plenty of CPU power to handle such a small amount of requests.

I would like to know how to configure Nginx to handle only one or two downloads at a time per server and queue the rest, to prevent the slowdowns I'm experiencing. I have tried various settings but haven't had much luck. I also wish there was a way to make the server dynamically speed up the downloads once resources open up. Right now if a download starts at a busy time it will be super slow and will continue to be super slow even if it becomes the only request. I a new to Nginx, and any advice means a lot.

Here is my main server conf file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  4;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_cache off;
    limit_req_zone $server_name zone=req_limit:10m rate=2r/s;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    log_format upstreamlog '$server_name to: $upstream_addr [$request] '
      'upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time '
      'msec $msec request_time $request_time';
    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    upstream notes {
        server 10.10.15.112:8080;
        server 10.10.15.214:8080;
        server 10.12.14.230:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;

        access_log /opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://notes;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            limit_req zone=req_limit burst=2 nodelay; # Apply request limiting
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;

            
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    include servers/*;
}
```